# PostgreSQL dump issues when importing into AWS RDS

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.4

I've been struggling with several adaptations (using `sed`) of a `pg_dump` output to match **AWS RDS**' restrictions on users/roles, but have come to a point where `pg_catalog` schema access is forbidden and is making a mess with the search path while re-creating the desired DB structure.

Initially we had:

ERROR:  permission denied for schema pg_catalog

Triggered from:

```
SET search_path = reports, pg_catalog;

--
-- Name: entrada_salida; Type: TYPE; Schema: reports; Owner: waypoint
--

CREATE TYPE entrada_salida AS (
        entrada timestamp with time zone,
        salida timestamp with time zone
);
```

The current pg_dump command has evolved to:

```
pg_dump -U waypoint -h $PGHOST --schema-only $PGDATABASE | sed  -- 's/COMMENT ON EXTENSION/-- COMMENT ON EXTENSION/g' | sed  -- 's/, pg_catalog;/;/g' | tr -d $'\r' > /tmp/schema.sql
```

But removing `pg_catalog` from pg_dump's generated script (`SET search_path` lines), has led to the following:

```
ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
```

Any workarounds that would work?

**Notes**

- Origin: PostgreSQL 9.4.9
- Added leading `--` (commented out) for `COMMENT ON EXTENSION` lines as existing extensions are not allowed to be modified in RDS
- `tr` used to filter out left over embedded CTRL-M characters in some user defined functions.

**EDIT**
Manually edited the dump to force the use of the `reports` for the `entrada_salida` type and I got:

```
 ERROR:  permission denied for schema reports
```

So I guess there are some permissions that didn't get migrated and, I'll have to look for them in the dump

Comment: `SET search_path = reports, pg_catalog;` does the `reports` schema exist at this place&time?

Comment: yes @wildplasser `CREATE SCHEMA reports;` is on line 169 of the script and the creation of type `entrada_salida` is in line 606

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "CREATE TYPE" is forbidden within AWS RDS as it requires superuser access. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html